# JTextField: Records inputs history like from Terminal

Tags: java, swing

I would like to develop a Swing application that may contain text field which will act like Terminal (*the console from Unix/Linux systems*).

Whenever a user entered a command, it will save into a container, then will be accessed thru up  or down arrow (<kbd>￪</kbd>/ <kbd>￬</kbd>).

I know it is possible but I still don't have the idea in implementing it right. My first implementation is to store the commands into a single text file, then accessed it in reverse order so that last input will be retrieve first.

My problem is that how will I know if I'm in the specified index (e.g. 2  <kbd>￪</kbd> arrows will go into length-2 index of file).

Comment: Do you mean you want to store the index between runs?

Comment: take the input ans store in a array.using keyevent take them back

Comment: Seems this could use the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)..

Comment: @MadProgrammer Index is just for the line code.

Comment: @EriezeLagera you not need a file.you only need to store commands until application close.collection is sufficient for that

Comment: I don't see why you want to maintain the information in the file, it would be faster to read it into memory and maintain it in some kind of `List` and persist it as required, that's just me though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very basic example but working fine.you can take user inputs when pressing enter and add them to a collection like arraylist ,vectors .i used vector in this example.when user hit enter store them in a collection and when user press (<kbd>￪</kbd>/ <kbd>￬</kbd>) ,take from it back and show in textarea.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;

public class terminal extends JFrame {

    Vector v = new Vector();
    JTextArea area;
    int pos = 0;

    public terminal() {
        setTitle("my terminal");
        JPanel j = new JPanel();
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        setSize(400,250);
        j.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        area = new JTextArea("terminal");
        area.setBackground(Color.black);
        area.setForeground(Color.white);
        area.setCaretColor(Color.white);
        area.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                area(evt);
            }

            private void area(KeyEvent evt) {
                int keyCode = evt.getKeyCode();
                if (keyCode == 38) {
                    try {
                        String store = (String) v.get(v.size() - 1 - pos);
                        replacer(store);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        //ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    pos++;
                    evt.consume();
                } else if (keyCode == 40) {
                    try {
                        String store = (String) v.get(v.size() - 1 - pos);
                        replacer(store);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        //ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    pos--;
                    evt.consume();
                } else if (keyCode == 10) {
                    v.add(linetext());
                }
            }
        });
        j.add(area);
        add(j);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    void replacer(String rep) {

        try {
            int caretOffset = area.getCaretPosition();
            int lineNumber = area.getLineOfOffset(caretOffset);
            int startOffset = area.getLineStartOffset(lineNumber);
            int endOffset = area.getLineEndOffset(lineNumber);

            area.replaceRange(rep, startOffset, endOffset);
        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
           //ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    String linetext() {
        String text = null;
        try {
            JTextArea ta = area;
            int offset = ta.getLineOfOffset(ta.getCaretPosition());
            int start = ta.getLineStartOffset(offset);
            int end = ta.getLineEndOffset(offset);
            text = ta.getText(start, (end - start));
        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
            //ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return text;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                terminal terminal = new terminal();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

output>>

[image]

Comment: You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others. You should also be using key bindings over `KeyListener`, see [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and isn't `Vector` deprecated in favour of `List`...

Comment: @fastsnail Sorry late responding. Your code actually works! But we should consider what MadProgrammer said, using Key Bindings is more convenient and key code should be compared to the constant variables. It will be more readable and efficient. But one more thing, can this be implemented to JTextField instead of JTextArea?

Comment: @EriezeLagera jtextField only support single line .if you want multiple lines then textarea is for that.however you can use multiple textfields to hold multiple lines.but why?textarea is simple.

Comment: @fastsnail Yeah you're right. I'll just change my JTextField into JTextArea with single-line view to hide the other inputs. Thanks!